# Limit Goal Seek searching parameters?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a Goal Seek function in VBA, which is trying to change Diameterindv/P/c16 until it makes QFuld/R/c18 larger than Q Max/N/c14.
R is a formular that calculates the flow based on the diameter in P. This must be larger than the nescesarry incoming flow in N.

I've added a screenshot and a bit of code. However when running the below code, I often get weird results (large negative numbers among them). Example is when running the code P is suddenly -63082144,16.

I'm wondering if it's possible for Goal Seek to only seek in prespecified numbers/range?
For instance, I only want the numbers it can use as a solution to be 188, 235, 297, 377, 500, 600.

Current wrong result:

[image]

Desired result in red:

[image]

```
Sub Nyberegning()

r = 3
Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
Cells(r, 18).GoalSeek goal:=Cells(r, 14) + 0.001, changingcell:=Cells(r, 16)
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and place a picture of your existing worksheet and how would you like it to look after goal seek processing? Otherwise, we cannot understand anything...

Comment: @FaneDuru Of course, I was a bit hasty in my first post.